# SQL query merge two columns from two tables in one column of resulting table?

Tags: sql, select, db2

I have the following tables:

T1

```
  ID 
  1
  2
  3
```

T2

```
ID  SERVICE
1   PSTN
1   ADSL
3   ADSL
```

T3

```
ID   DEV
1    3G
3    2G
```

I want as output

```
ID  SERVICE/DEV
1      PSTN
1      ADSL
1      3G
2
3      ADSL
3     2G
```

How to merge this?

I can not use classic `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

Total number in output table for one id should be the summary of `T2+T3 (FOR ID=1 2+1=3)` but for `ID=2` it also should exist in table output with blank second column.

Answer (score 7):

You can simply combine the results of the two tables specifically `T2` and `T3` using `union` inside a subquery the later join it with `T1` using `LEFT JOIN`. Try this,

```
SELECT t1.ID, b.Service
FROM T1 LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT ID, Service FROM T2
        UNION ALL
        SELECT ID, Dev AS Service FROM T3
    ) b ON t1.ID = b.ID
```

Additionally, you can use `COALESCE` if you want to customize the columns having `null` values. So in the example below, since `2` has *no service*, it will show `-none-` instead of `null`

```
SELECT t1.ID, COALESCE(b.Service, '-none-') Service
FROM T1 LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT ID, Service FROM T2
        UNION ALL
        SELECT ID, Dev AS Service FROM T3
    ) b ON t1.ID = b.ID
```

## [See SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/52b2e/13)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this.

```
SELECT T1.ID, service "SERVICE/DEV"
FROM T1, T2
WHERE T1.ID = T2.ID(+)
UNION
SELECT T1.ID, dev "service/dev"
FROM T1, T3 
WHERE T1.ID = T3.ID(+);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want union/union all?

```
select *
from ((select id, service
       from t2
      ) union all
      (select id, service
       from t3
      ) union all
      (select id, NULL as service
       from t1
       where t1.id not in (select id from t2) and
             t1.id not in (select id from t3)
      )
     ) t
```

The `NOT IN` in the `WHERE` clause may not be the most efficient way to do this.  But is this the result you are aiming for?